# cron.sh - expr and expr command not found

Tags: magento-1.9, cron

Incipit: I have never used sh before.
My server is using linux RedHat and every time I run `cron.sh`, the server sends me an email with:

```
shop/cron.sh: line 45: expr: command not found
shop/cron.sh: line 46: ps: command not found
```

Cron string: `/bin/sh /home/mn0198/public_html/shop/cron.sh`
I have read that it may be a problem of portability, but I don't even know where I should start.

```
#!/bin/sh
#
# Magento
#
# NOTICE OF LICENSE
#
# This source file is subject to the Open Software License (OSL 3.0)
# that is bundled with this package in the file LICENSE.txt.
# It is also available through the world-wide-web at this URL:
# http://opensource.org/licenses/osl-3.0.php
# If you did not receive a copy of the license and are unable to
# obtain it through the world-wide-web, please send an email
# to license@magento.com so we can send you a copy immediately.
#
# DISCLAIMER
#
# Do not edit or add to this file if you wish to upgrade Magento to newer
# versions in the future. If you wish to customize Magento for your
# needs please refer to http://www.magento.com for more information.
#
# @category    Mage
# @package     Mage
# @copyright  Copyright (c) 2006-2015 X.commerce, Inc. (http://www.magento.com)
# @license    http://opensource.org/licenses/osl-3.0.php  Open Software License (OSL 3.0)
#
if [ ! "$1" = "" ] ; then
    CRONSCRIPT=$1
else
    CRONSCRIPT=cron.php
fi

MODE=""
if [ ! "$2" = "" ] ; then
    MODE=" $2"
fi

PHP_BIN=`which php`

# absolute path to magento installation
INSTALLDIR=`echo $0 | sed 's/cron\.sh//g'`

#   prepend the intallation path if not given an absolute path
# the following lines are 45 and 46
if [ "$INSTALLDIR" != "" -a "`expr index $CRONSCRIPT /`" != "1" ];then
    if ! ps auxwww | grep "$INSTALLDIR$CRONSCRIPT$MODE" | grep -v grep 1>/dev/null 2>/dev/null ; then
        $PHP_BIN $INSTALLDIR$CRONSCRIPT$MODE &
    fi
else
    if  ! ps auxwww | grep "$CRONSCRIPT$MODE" | grep -v grep | grep -v cron.sh 1>/dev/null 2>/dev/null ; then
        $PHP_BIN $CRONSCRIPT$MODE &
    fi
fi
```

**EDIT - Command test**
I have run these through putty ssh(I don't know if it's correct):

```
command -v expr >/dev/null 2>&1 || { echo >&2 "not installed.";}
hash expr >/dev/null 2>&1 || { echo >&2 "not installed.";}
type expr >/dev/null 2>&1 || { echo >&2 "not installed.";}


command -v ps >/dev/null 2>&1 || { echo >&2 "not installed.";}
hash ps >/dev/null 2>&1 || { echo >&2 "not installed.";}
type ps >/dev/null 2>&1 || { echo >&2 "not installed.";}
```

All of them return `not installed`

Comment: What is the hosting operating system? `expr` and `ps` are standard linux CLI utilities. http://www.computerhope.com/unix/uexpr.htm and http://www.computerhope.com/unix/ups.htm

Comment: Try with /bin/bash /home/mn0198/public_html/shop/cron.sh

Comment: @Imaginaerum Already tried with no success...

Comment: @B00MER This is what I havefound. Siteground: `This server has a standard (Linux RedHat) setup`, from the documentaion: `CentOS` and with  `uname -a`: `Linux x86_64 GNU/Linux`

Comment: Try `/usr/bin/sh` instead of `/bin/sh`, also update your question with the full header in tact for the `cron.sh` file as the first line may need to be modified to `#/usr/bin/sh` as well. Also you can test `expr` and `ps` from CLI to help validate any issues.  You may also check to see what your current `PATH` is.

Comment: @B00MER I have changed to `/usr/bin/sh`, do I need to change also the header? Also I will try to test `expr` and `ps` once I understamd how to do it. When you say `PATH`, do you mean `INSTALLDIR`?

Comment: @B00MER I have tried to test the function expr and ps with negative results (if the test mode is correct)

Comment: Normally `ps` and `expr` are standard out of box utilities in linux. Whom are you hosting with? Also PATH I mean: http://www.linfo.org/path_env_var.html

Comment: @B00MER Siteground, I have just opened a ticket to have explanations, also I have run `env` on ssh console and it shows:`SHELL=/bin/bash` , should I change the header of the `cron.sh` file and edit the cronjob line according to the result?

Comment: That may explain it, `bash` and  `sh` are two different shells. http://man.cx/sh & http://man.cx/bash A shortcut may be to just use `php -f cron.php` and bypass `cron.sh` although `cron.sh` will do a `ps` grep for any existing processes and not execute.  https://askubuntu.com/questions/141928/what-is-difference-between-bin-sh-and-bin-bash

Comment: @B00MER Well, they answered me that shared hosting plans have a lighter OS which don't include those two commands(???)...so yeah, it's pointless to run the sh if `ps` is not executed, beside the correct execution of the hearthbeat function of `AOE_scheduler` module...is it possible to use `let` instead of `expr` and `pgrep`  instead of `ps`?

Comment: Use `php -f cron.php` instead in your cron if your host doesn't support, `ps` or `expr`.

Comment: @B00MER Ok, thank you very much for your help

Comment: Updated with an answer if its correct feel free to accept. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `php -f cron.php` instead in your cron if your host doesn't support, `ps` or `expr`.

Answer (score 1):

Just using `php -f cron.php` doesn't do what cron.sh does.

`cron.sh` tries to prevent multiple instances of `cron.php` while `php -f cron.php` just starts another cron while the first might still run.

that could lead to dead locks!

Edit: Perhaps that's a work around (Mittwald provides that solution)?! It utilizes a lock file instead:

```
#!/bin/sh
# Compatible versions: 1.9.2.1, 1.9.2.0, 1.9.1.1, 1.9.1.0, 1.9.0.1, 1.8.1.0, 1.8.0.0
lockfile=/tmp/cron.lock
PHP_BIN=/usr/local/bin/php
ABSOLUTE_PATH=$(cd $(dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}") && pwd)/$(basename "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}")
INSTALLDIR=${ABSOLUTE_PATH%/*}

function cleanup() {
    for cpid in $(jobs -p); do kill $cpid; done
    rm -f $lockfile
}

trap cleanup 1 2 3 6 9 15

if [ ! -f $lockfile ];then
    echo $$ > $lockfile
else
    exit 0
fi

if [ -n "$1" ] ; then
    CRONSCRIPT=$1
else
    CRONSCRIPT=cron.php
fi

for i in default always; do
        $PHP_BIN $INSTALLDIR/$CRONSCRIPT -m$i 1>/dev/null 2>&1 &
done
wait
rm -f $lockfile

exit 0
```

Rico

Comment: I know, unfortunately the linux comands necessary to accomplish this task aren't supported by my host...

Comment: I edited my answer with a possible solution